# Проверка голосования на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, нужно сделать голосование на более 100 страниц (что-то типа оценки статьи). Начал думать как это реализовать, и остановился на проверке, голосовал данный человек уже или нет (чтоб избежать повторного голосования). Т.к. на сайте будет регистрация я остановился на следующем варианте:

Человек регистрируется, после чего может голосовать (не зарегистрированные пользователи не могут голосовать). После чего голосует, и в базу заносится его `login` и создается `cookie` к примеру с `check=true`.

*Для каждой статьи в БД будет столбец с логинами проголосовавших.

Далее будет проверка, если `check=true`, то убрать кнопку для голосования. Даже если человек почистит куки, то будет следующая проверка: Если будет кука то проверки в базе не будет. Но если ее не будет, то тогда проверяем `login==$login` и делаем куку с `check=true`

Правильное решение или нет? Может есть варианты куда легче?

ПОПРАВКА:

Кто как создает БД для таких вещей? Есть 2 варианта:
1) Сделать 1 таблицу куда будут идти ВСЕ голоса. Конечно же, туда будет заносится и ID голосования.
2) Создать таблицы для каждого голосования отдельно.

Comment: А для чего cookie? Почему бы при проверке целиком не ориентироваться на базу данных? Или вы хотите дергать базу данных только при попытке голосования?

Comment: Именно, не хочется лишний раз делать поиск по базе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в БД я бы делал таблицу с primary или unique ключём сразу из двух полей:  `article_id` и `user_id` – это гарантирует в самих данных, что один юзер только один раз голосует.

При авторизации я бы отдавал в клиент json массив с перечисленными `article_id` в которых юзер уже голосовал, чтобы даже не предлагать ему это там делать повторно. Это лучше, чем cookies, так как не привязывается к компьютеру, браузеру, и его потенциальному нежеланию работать с куками.

Comment: можно ещё в session писать